# User asks almost the same question 4 hours later again

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

How to handle this: [James marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7343479/james-marcus) asked almost the same question 4 hours later today

1. [Phone regex to accept spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978636/phone-regex-to-accept-spaces)
2. [phone regex space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980395/phone-regex-space)

The only difference is that the latter question contains another test case (highlighting added):

> For example +57 52 5252255 should pass, but currently it's not
>   passing. **also "+91 9 820 09 8200" should pass so a space anywhere is
>   acceptable**

And the fiddle was updated to include this sample as well:
https://jsfiddle.net/ofn9knay/267/
https://jsfiddle.net/ofn9knay/268/

What to do: Flag it as duplicate, flag it to a moderator, or leave it alone?

I flagged the second one as duplicate but nobody else seems to care. That's why I  post here.

Comment: It looks like a mod has merged the two question.

Comment: I think it was merged. The remaining answer contains the answers from both questions. Anyway, good outcome. Handled in a nice way. Thanks, everybody.

Comment: Vote for closure. Second question as dupe of the first.

Comment: This is the one scenario where the close-as-dupe dialog lets you chose a dupe-target that does not yet have an answer.

Comment: Snark-laden comments are usually the best way to set these types of users straight.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> What to do: Flag it as duplicate, flag it to a moderator, or leave it alone?

Simple **Flag it as duplicate**

Please read this comment of [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872918/how-to-go-to-different-activity-each-time-a-list-from-recyclerview-is-clicked-u#comment88769034_50872918)  about repeating questions

> Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers didn't work, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since you seem to have gotten your solution there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Comment: I did. But no one else so far.

Comment: @wp78de check updated answer

Comment: Yes, this is to the point. Maybe someone with a dupehammer can handle this real quick.

Comment: It won't bump to the top of newest queue, however.

Comment: @wp78de - I always include a link to the original in the comment and open with a very clear statement like "Please don't repost [your earlier question](http://example.com). Instead, ..." That makes it easy for close-voters to know what's going on at a glance and act accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

You flag it as duplicate and want to get the attention of the community. If it is a legitimate flag you can send close vote requests to the [socvr](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room.

There are tools for that too: https://socvr.org/tools/userscripts

Comment: Great, I did not know that. Cool stuff!