# Own question without answer(s)

Tags: support

What can I do if my question stays unanswered?

Can I ask again after X days?

And/or should I use bounty?

Comment: Bounty. Do not ask again, it will be downvoted, closed as a dupe and/or deleted. You can also provide edits to the question which may be beneficial. Have a look at [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: See [Help center/no-one answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers). Never re-ask the same question

Comment: I think you do not have enough rep to offer a bounty yet. So focus on editing the question to improve it, which will make it more likely that it is answered. Also, edits "bump" the question up, so it will get more views. Asking the same question again, certainly **not**.

Comment: @yivi 75 rep unlocks the bounty privilege. So at the moment of writing the comment the OP has enough. I'm agreeing though, that improving the question is most likely the best course of action to try first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What can I do if my question stays unanswered?

**You can offer bounty**, But *first* make sure you’ve asked a good question.

Some basic steps for how to ask good question (as per my opinion):

1. Properly describe your problem.
2. Add effort that you tried to solve the problem.
3. If you done some research related to the problem, add it along with question.
4. Provide status and progress updates if any one has a suggested solution.

> Can I ask again after X days?

**No**, it will flagged as duplicate. You can read here about [repeating questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369940/user-asks-almost-the-same-question-4-hours-later-again/369941#369941).

> And/or should I use bounty?

Yes